# Как узнать сколько было показов/переходов по картинке на сайте?

Tags: javascript, php, статистика

Коллеги приветствую. В разработке сервис с иллюстрациями . Задача собрать статистику для дальнейшей работы.
Необходимо узнать сколько было показов иллюстрации и сколько было переходов на страницу с иллюстрацией.
Не понимаю с какой стороны подойти к решению проблемы. Смотреть на область фокуса пользователя , если фокус более 2 секунд -> смотреть какие иллюстрации попали в область фокуса -> отправлять данные на сервер и как-то анализировать. Пока есть такая идея, но как это нормальное реализовать не понятно пока. не хочется городить огород . Подскажите сталкивались вы на практике с такой задачей ? как можно это реализовать на фронте ? есть библиотеки или технические решение, где можно что-то подсмотреть для себя ?) заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что такое **область фокуса пользователя**?

Comment: есть страница поиска, страница пака . на этих страницах есть иллюстрации. считаем сколько раз иллюстрация была отображена на сайте. по идее если пользователь быстро пролистал страницу мы не считаем это показом. есть отдельная страница , где мы показываем иллюстрацию в fullpreview + всякие теги, похожие иллюстрации. переход на эту страницу - это переход (не показ).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю так. Если эти картинки выводятся из базы, то для каждой картинки есть отдельная строка с другими дополнительными информациями  id и т.д. Вам необходимо создать в таблице столбец kol_prosmotr когда картинка открывается в новой странице view.php на этой странице написать запрос. Взять id этой строки и без всяких проверок когда страница загружается или обновляется создать update запрос и к значению kol_prosmotr добавить 1.

Answer (score 0):

1. Чтобы узнать сколько было переходов по картинке. Навешиваете обработчик клика на картинку - и по клику отправляете данные на сервер
2. Узнать сколько было показов картинки - логируете все запросы приходящие из браузера, берете все запросы к картинке - получаете кол-во ее показов